# Parâmetros GET adicionais não funciona com htaccess

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site m páginas dinâmicas e url amigável, meu problema é o seguinte:

Quando coloco no link o id pra visualizar os detalhes do imóvel `<a href="/imovel?id<echo $row['id_imovel']>">`, o arquivo imovel.php não recebe o id que foi enviado via get.

Na url, quando recebe imovel inclui imovel.php, mas quando é imovel?id=3174 por exemplo não é feito a inclusão.

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```

PHP:

```
function getHome(){
        $url = $_GET['pagina'];
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        $url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'content' : $url[0]);


        if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php');
        }elseif(file_exists('/tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
        }elseif(file_exists('/tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php');
        }else{
            require_once('tpl/404.php');
        }
```

Como resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Isto é porque falta a flag `QSA`

Você deve fazer assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA]
```

Se não quer "ocultar" o ID também, pode usar desta maneira (com RegEX):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA] #Outras páginas ou página sem ID
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?pagina=$1&id=$2 [QSA] #Qualquer página com ID
```

Se quiser usar `id=` apenas na página imóvel, então use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^imovel/(\d+)$ index.php?pagina=imovel&id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Solucionado amigão! Obrigado! Como posso esconder o id, deixando imovel/3174 por exemplo?

Comment: @IgorSilva editei a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Inserir a opção no meu htaccess para qualquer página com ID e não funcionou. Eu tenho que tratar o id na função getHome do código php acima? Esse é link que vai para página imovel com o id: <a href="<?php echo DIR?>/imovel?id=<?php echo $id;?>">.

Comment: Não @IgorSilva eu passei pelo `&id=$1` então basta usar `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Ficaria dessa froma: <a href="<?php echo DIR?>/imovel/<?php echo $id;?>">

Comment: @IgorSilva isso mesmo :) pois o `index.php?pagina=imovel&id=$1 [QSA]` já interpreta o `id=`, então o endereço deve ser algo como `http://exemplo/imovel/10001` e quando usar `$_GET['id']` vai retornar `10001` por exemplo

Comment: Retornou Not Found, o final da minha url é esse:www.site.com/exclusive/imovel/3239

Comment: @IgorSilva a pasta `exclusive` existe? note que usei `^imovel/(\d+)$` e não `^exclusive/imovel/(\d+)$`. Você está mudando o padrão da url, não tem como o mod_rewrite entender tal mudança se você não editar o .htaccess pra isto.

Comment: Meu site n fica na raiz, a url dele fica assim: site.com/exlcusive/imovel/ID, vou inserir o ^exclusive/imovel pra ver se dá certo.

Comment: @IgorSilva Você quer dizer que `exlcusive` é uma pasta real?

Comment: Sim, pode posta a url do site aqui?

Comment: @IgorSilva Pode! Só me responde uma coisa o .htaccess está em que pasta?

Comment: O site é esse: http://himoveis.com/exclusive/   o htaccess esta dentro da pasta exclusive.

Comment: @IgorSilva amanhã nos falamos :)

Comment: Vlw! muito obrigado!